# Hangout app http-requests are blocked

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I've integrated a Hangout Button to my web site. This button has my Hangout app in startApps. This app sends request to my web site. It worked before but now I get the following error:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_/g2zuejstqkd5bj54rxafn542rya?hl=ru' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://myUrl': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

So I guess Hangout Button generated http url before but it generates https url now. What can I do about it? Well... I could make my site work with https but doing it just to overcome hangouts limitations seems unreasonable. And what if Hangout button starts generating http urls in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up switching to SSL. It resolved the described problem